# WlanGetNetworkBssList()-like commands do not compile with g++

Tags: c++, g++, mingw32, mingw-w64, wlanapi

I'm trying to compile a program that prints all available wifi access points including their BSSID.

The example of WlanGetAvailableNetworkList() function on MSDN website compiled just fine when removing the flag part with  WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED.

To print BSSIDs as well I edited that code. I added the following functions and structs:

WlanGetNetworkBssList()
WlanScan()
PWLAN_BSS_LIST
PWLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES
PDOT11_MAC_ADDRESS.

All of them except PDOT11_MAC_ADDRESS are marked as 'not declared in this scope'.

My compile command is:

```
g++ -o WlanAP2 WlanAP2.cpp -lwlanapi -lole32
```

(The same one worked for the MSDN example.)

My include order is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <windows.h>  
#include <wlanapi.h>  
#include <objbase.h>
```

What am I missing?
Is there another library to be included?
Why do especially these commands not compile?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)